# What is django.utils.datetime_safe and should I use it instead of standard datetime?

Tags: python, django, datetime

What are the differences? Is it safer to use `datetime_safe`? I can't find any documentation on this class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is noted in the source code for `datetime_safe`:

```
# Python's datetime strftime doesn't handle dates before 1900.
# These classes override date and datetime to support the formatting of a date
# through its full "proleptic Gregorian" date range.
```

Huh.

Comment: Note that `datetime_safe` will be removed in [Django 5.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-5-0)

Comment: Already removed from [Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#id2) so far.

Comment: @Sadra not removed in Django4, only deprecated, will raise warnings "The django.utils.datetime_safe module is deprecated."